# React setState causes a "cannot render object" error

Tags: reactjs

I have a simple statefull component with a form.

```
export class example extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    this.state = {
      issue: {id: '', isValid: false}
    }
    this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this)
  }

  onSubmit (e) {
    fetch('/some/api/path').then((newIssue) => {
      newIssue.json().then(convertedIssue => {
        this.setState({issue: convertedIssue})  
      })
    })
  }

  render() {
    const issue = this.state.issue
    return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
          ID: {issue.id}
          ...
        </form>
      </div>
     )
   }
```

The issue comes when I get the API response. The response is a simple object that maps the the issue object that initialized the state in the constructor. When I try to call `setState({issue: issue})` I get the error: `Uncaught (in promise) Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: Sun Nov 06 2016 16:00:00 GMT-0800 (PST)). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.`

I can hack around this error by changing the call from `setState({issue: newIssue})` to `setState({newIssue})`

Why is this? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is not that you're assigning an object to the value of `this.state.issue`, that is valid.

The error message is indicating that somewhere in your component or children you're trying to render the value of `this.state.issue`. However React doesn't render objects directly.

So if you did something like

```
render() {
 return <div>{this.state.issue}</div>
}
```

or if you passed this.state.issue as a prop and then tried to render it in a child component, you would also receive an error.

Before rendering you need to select what part of `this.state.issue` you'd like to display. This would be valid:

```
render() {
  return (
    <span>Issue Id: {this.state.issue.id}</span>
  )
}
```

Comment: I do destructure `this.state.issue` and render that data directly in the JSX. Could that be the cause?

Comment: Yes that would cause an error. So something like `const { issue } = this.state` and then you try to render `{issue}` would throw an error. Select a piece of issue you'd like to display like `issue.id`

Comment: You could render `{JSON.stringify(issue)}` after destructuring if you wanted to see the entire object.